# React - appending an empty row to a table

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

I am currently building an application that renders a table but in the first instance the only thing that renders are the column headers. What I would like to know is how I would then go about giving a user the choice to add a row with no data that they can then edit to add data that they want to put in the cells of the row. The headers are generated by a form with a dynamic amount of inputs so theoretically there could be a lot and the added row would need to reflect this also. I would like to try and avoid using a plugin if possible as well.

The app is being built with React and for the moment I am using flux architecture.

Fast answers with examples would be very much appreciated!

Thanks for your time

Here is where the whole table renders:

```
import React from 'react';
import TableHeader from './TableHeader.jsx';
import TableBody from './TableBody.jsx';

export default class Table extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <table className="table table-striped dali-table">
                <thead><TableHeader /></thead>
                <tbody><TableBody /></tbody>
            </table>
        );
    }
}
```

Here is the code for rendering the column headers:

```
import React from 'react';
import AppStore from '../../stores/AppStore';

export default class TableHeader extends React.Component {

    addHeaders() {
        let headerArray = AppStore.getTable().columns;
        let headerList = headerArray.map((element, index) => {
            return (
                <th key={index} id={element.id} className="text-center">{element.name}</th>
            );
        });
        return headerList;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <tr>{this.addHeaders()}</tr>
        );
    }
}
```

And I don't really have any code for the body of the table, as that is the bit which I am struggling with!

Okay so I think I'm making some headway! Thanks for the help so far! Here is what I have at the moment (I will be separating it out later, just want to get it working first!):

```
import React from 'react';
import AppStore from '../../stores/AppStore';

export default class Table extends React.Component {
    state = {rows: [], isEditing: false};

    render() {

        let {rows, isEditing} = this.state;

        let headerArray = AppStore.getTable().columns;

        const handleEdit = (row) => {
            this.setState({isEditing: true});
        };

        const handleAddRowClickEvent = () => {
            let rows = this.state.rows;
            rows.push({isNew: true, isEditing: false});
            this.setState({rows: rows});
        };

        return (
            <div>
                <div className="row" id="table-row">
                    <table className="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>{headerArray.map((element, index) => {
                                return (
                                    <th key={index} id={element.id} className="text-center">{element.name}</th>
                                );})}
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {rows.map((row, index) => row.isEditing ?
                                <RowForm formKey={index} key={index} /> :
                                <tr key={index}>
                                    {headerArray.map((element, index) => {
                                        return (
                                            <td key={index} id={element.id}></td>
                                        );
                                    })}
                                    <td>
                                        <button onClick={handleEdit(row)}>Edit</button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>)}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-xs-12 de-button">
                        <button type="button" className="btn btn-success" onClick={handleAddRowClickEvent}>Add Row</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Need help on adding the row don't know what to push into the empty rows array! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main idea is add flag to each row so you can know the status for each row, is it in edit mode or display mode

```
render(){
   const handleEdit = (row) => {
      // toggle isEditing flag
    };
    return (<tbody>
    { 
      rows.map((row) => row.isEditing ?
        <RowForm formKey={row.id} key={row.id}/> :
        <tr key={row.id}>
          <td>{row.id}</td>
          <td>{row.name}</td>
            <button onClick={handleEdit(row)}>
             Edit
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr> 
    }
    </tbody>);
}
```

Check this example [source code](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/blob/master/src/containers/Widgets/Widgets.js) / [demo](https://react-redux.herokuapp.com/widgets)

Comment: Hi Nour thanks for the answer. The table actually starts with no data in the row so I can't extract information from them until data is entered into them but I see where you are going with it and will certainly try and incorporate it into my project!

Comment: But you can use `defaultProps` to display the the init render
I hope i understand you correctly
And i tried to help :)

Comment: One quick question: the editing stuff I am actually fine with the editing stuff, and was planning on doing something similar to what you proposed so thanks for that again. I want the table to initialise with no data but then be able to add a row (with no data) when a button is clicked. Would I do this in a similar way to the way you suggest to toggle between editing and display or should I go about it in a different way?

Comment: if the init table don't have any row that mean it's empty array so rows = []
after the user click `add` you can add item to this array rows.push({id:lastId++, name:'', editing:false})

Comment: if you will fill the table via XHR request then you should use `componentDidMount` event and then setState({rows:response})

Comment: I'm being a bit of a dope at the moment (its also part of the reason why I am completely confused)! If the the table starts with no data then how can I get it to render the correct amount of rows considering that the number of column headers is dynamically generated???

Comment: The table is being filled by the user in the first instance and then saved

Comment: You need 2 loops 1- for rows 2- for columns and you should follow the indexes to know which cell updated

Comment: Would it be better to do all of it in the same component then? Rather than splitting it into multiple components

Comment: i prefer mix, main component to call subcomponents and trigger actions
, and the subcomponents only for render and they have props to call function in the main component

Comment: Hi Nour thanks for your help! I updated my question with my new code at the bottom (I left it all in one big chunk but I will be separating it once I get it working). One part I'm not sure on is what I should be pushing to create the new row as it doesn't have an id yet?! Do you think that I am on the right track anyway?

Comment: push empty fields for array/string fields and for Id you can assign 0 or -1
and then you can filter it by id === -1 or  id === 0 so you can know which rows are new

Comment: or may you can use 2 flags editing,isNew so you can follow the status for each row

Comment: Not getting that could you provide a quick example?

Comment: I mean you have flag isEditing to know if the row in edit mode
you can do the same for the new rows, isNew for new rows
the benefit of has this flag is save the new rows to database

Comment: Oh I already added that flag but I'm now getting an infinite loop with the error: Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.
Is it a problem with the render method of the <tbody> ?

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Posting some code snippets will help one provide better answers</strike>

So, to create a dynamic row you could do something like:

```
import React from 'react';
import AppStore from '../../stores/AppStore';

export default class TableBody extends React.Component {

    addRows() {
        // This gets the number of columns in your header from your backend
        let noOfColumns = AppStore.getColumnSize();

        // loop from 1 to noOfColumns and return:
        return (
              <td><input placeholder='Enter Value'/></td>
          );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <tr>{this.addRows()}</tr>
        );
    }
}
```

Then add TableBody to your Table Class.

PS - The above is just code snippets and is somewhat pseudo-code. You also need to handle the 'input field' correctly as per React Documentation recommendation: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html

Comment: Added in some snippets!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11439624)

Comment: @dotnetom with my current reputation I couldn't comment on their question! No other way to solicit clarification?

Comment: @user1609848 do the snippets I added help in any way? I am still struggling with this problem and any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: So that is straight forward. You can set the state as you have said. So in your class you will have something like: 

this.state = {rows: []} And this can be done in your constructor. Then when you are have fetched the size from the server, you can update the rows and this in turn will re-render.